# Providing Read access to the Welcome Page

Tags: 2010, permissions

I am in the process of retiring a site collection (SharePoint 2010). I have a splash page (splash.aspx) located in a document library on the root web and have set the Welcome Page to this splash page.

I want to give all users read access to this splash page, but no other pages. It's simple enough to break inheritance on the actual page, but this does not allow them to access the "Welcome Page" by navigating to the site's root URL.

Site = http://example.com/

Welcome Page = http://example.com/Pages/splash.aspx

After removing read access for all users on the site and granting read access to splash.aspx, users can access splash.aspx directly, but are unable to access http://example.com/

Any solutions? I have read it may be possible to do this by setting up Anonymous Access (something I probably can't do due to policy). An alternative I'm considering is breaking inheritance on all subwebs and libraries in the root, removing all auth'd users from everything, then giving auth users read access to the root site and splash.aspx (however, this seems flimsy..)

Comment: As a note- UI or Powershell solutions are fine, but I don't believe I'd be able to solve this through a server side solution deployment.

Comment: This is a bit crude but if you want to show a splash page anytime when someone reaches any page of the sitecollection you can create a new masterpage containing only your splash HTML and none of the SP stuff. Through SPD you can assign it to the sites. Now you don't need to change permissions. Of course people Can still access content via outlook, Windows Explorer etc.

Comment: thanks- this is an interesting work-around. it's unfortunately complex for something that should be simple.